# my angularjs ng-controller doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

this is my first code in angularjs and I completely don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I created this:

```
var app = angular.module('koloApp', []);    
app.controller('circleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.kolor1 = 'red';
    $scope.kolor2 = 'yellow';   
}]);'
```

and with this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl" ng-app="koloApp">
<head>
<title>KOLO</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dyrektywy/kolo/kolo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <kolo-directive ng-click="clickMe()" kolor-wypelnienia ="'navy'" kolor-otoczenia="'yellow'"></kolo-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this directive:

```
var app = angular.module('koloApp', []);

app.directive('koloDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'js/dyrektywy/kolo/kolo.html',
    transclude: true,

    link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
        $scope.clickMe = function () {
            alert("kliknąłeś w kółeczko");
        }
    },

    scope:
        {
            kolorKola: '=kolorWypelnienia',
            kolorObwodki:'=kolorOtoczenia'
        },

};

});
```

everything works fine. But, when I want to use ng-controller in my html it completely doesn't work. I tried to use it like that:
  `<div ng-controller: "circleController">` and in console I got this error: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=circleController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

I don't know what is wrong with this controller. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the colon with an equal sign.

It should be:

```
<div ng-controller = "circleController">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided your controller in your HTML.

You have to provide like

```
<div ng-controller= "circleController">
```

instead of

```
<div ng-controller: "circleController">
```

Check following :

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="koloApp">
<div ng-controller="circleController">
    <kolo-directive ng-click="clickMe()" kolor-wypelnienia ="'navy'" kolor-otoczenia="'yellow'"></kolo-directive>
</div>

 </div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('koloApp', []);    
app.controller('circleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.kolor1 = 'red';
    $scope.kolor2 = 'yellow';   
}]);

app.directive('koloDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>Changed your <b>templateUrl</b> to <b>template</b> for showing this example</h1>',
    transclude: true,

    link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
        $scope.clickMe = function () {
            alert("kliknąłeś w kółeczko");
        }
    },

    scope:
        {
            kolorKola: '=kolorWypelnienia',
            kolorObwodki:'=kolorOtoczenia'
        },

};

});
```

Check this fiddle : [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/agvTz/476/)